# Change Height of mdl-layout-header mdl-layout-header-row

Tags: css, material-design-lite

how to set CSS to change height for this Material Design Lite Header.

```
  <!-- MDL-LAYOUT - HEADER -->
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">

      </div>
  </header>

.mdl-layout__header{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid gold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gold;
    color: gold;
    height: 16px !important;
}
.mdl-layout__header-row{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    color: gold;
    height: 16px !important;
}
```

I can see mdl-layout-header-row height change but cannot get mdl-layout__header height changed!

Comment: What have you already tried yourself? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have to overwrite the `min-height` property (no need to use `!important`).

[**Pen demo**](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/xXrzWP?editors=1100)